# Contact Form 'Name' field validation troubles

Tags: jquery

I'm new to PHP and have been piecing together my own contact form...

I'm  having trouble getting the form to not-validate in scenario 2 below. Code Also below..

**SCENARIO 1:** 2 letters or numbers inputted = error pops up and mail does not send.

**SCENARIO 2:** 3+ numbers are inputted = error pops up, but mail DOES send.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#contact_email").focus(function(){
  if($("#contact_name").val().length < 3){
    $("#contact_name").css("border", "solid 1px #D295B5");
  }else {
    if(allLetter($("#contact_name").val())){
      $("#contact_name").css("border", "solid 1px #D295B5");
    }else {
      $("#contact_name").css("border", "solid 1px #DADB93");
    }
  }
});


function allLetter(inputtxt){
var letters = /^[A-Z a-z]+$/;
if(inputtxt.match(letters)){return false;}
else{return true;}
}
```

Any idea's what I am missing? So that if ANY numbers are inputted into the name field, it will not send.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are running the tests when the input is focused (`.focus()`) but you probably want them to run on `.submit()` of the form.

You then want to `return false` after your border style change to prevent the form submitting.

So:

```
$("#contact_email").closest('form').submit(function(){

    // Your tests...
    return false;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will sound silly, but I've found that sometimes the order you put your functions in will affect the logical output of the script. So, try putting your `function allLetter(inputtxt)` code above your `$(document).ready(function()`

```
function allLetter(inputtxt){
var letters = /^[A-Z a-z]+$/;
if(inputtxt.match(letters)){return false;}
else{return true;}
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#contact_email").focus(function(){
  if($("#contact_name").val().length < 3){
    $("#contact_name").css("border", "solid 1px #D295B5");
  }else {
    if(allLetter($("#contact_name").val())){
      $("#contact_name").css("border", "solid 1px #D295B5");
    }else {
      $("#contact_name").css("border", "solid 1px #DADB93");
    }
  }
});
```

That will allow the function to be in the cache when it's called.